# Undefined symbols while linking OSMalloc.h using clang on OS X

Tags: c, macos, kernel, clang, kernighan-and-ritchie

Hello and thank you for your assistance.

I'm attempting to create a simple 'hello world' using only low-level OS X kernel calls to allocate memory and write out to stdout.  Why? I'm finishing up chapter 8 of 2nd Edition K&R which is focused on writing standard file library from scratch. It is, of course, totally out of date but the concept of the chapter remains. Anyway, I cannot seem to figure out how to properly link  to get everything to work out and are thus earning myself lots of nice undefined symbol errors.

I have parsed through many other questions causing the same error, but have not found any that address how to link in the kernel library I'm attempting to use.  The crazy long path in the third #include was needed to just get the thing to compile even prior to the link errors.

The Code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h> // equivalent to (K&R) #include "syscalls.h"
#include </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/libkern/OSMalloc.h> // for low-level memory allocation

#define MINSTDIOTAG "com.apple.minstdio" // Used by OSMalloc from <libkern/OSMalloc.h>
#define PAGE_SIZE_64K (64 * 1024)        // Page size to allocate

int main(void) {

    char *base    = NULL; // Memory buffer
    char *ptr     = base; // Location in buffer

    // Create tag
    OSMallocTag mytag = OSMalloc_Tagalloc(MINSTDIOTAG, OSMT_DEFAULT);

    // Attempt to allocate PAGE_SIZE_64K of memory
    if ((base = (char *)OSMalloc(PAGE_SIZE_64K, mytag)) == NULL)
        return 1;
    ptr = base;

    // Stuff the buffer with stuff
    *ptr++ = 'f';
    *ptr++ = 'o';
    *ptr++ = 'o';
    *ptr++ = '\n';
    *ptr   = '\0';

    // Write it out to stdout
    (void)write(STDOUT_FILENO, base, (size_t)(ptr - base));

    // Free allocated memory
    OSFree(base, PAGE_SIZE_64K, mytag);

    // Get out of Dodge City, Kansas
    return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
BIN = ../../bin
ODIR = obj
CC = cc
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -Wall -g -I.
_OBJ = minstdio3.o
_BIN = minstdio3
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(_BIN)

clean:
    rm -rv $(ODIR) $(_BIN)

minstdio3: $(ODIR)/minstdio3.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
    cp -v $@ $(BIN)/$@

$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    mkdir -pv $(ODIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Errors Received:

```
Todds-MBP-2:cbasics todddecker$ make
mkdir -pv obj
cc -std=c99 -Wall -g -I. -c -o obj/minstdio3.o minstdio3.c
cc -std=c99 -Wall -g -I. obj/minstdio3.o -o minstdio3
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OSFree", referenced from:
      _main in minstdio3.o
  "_OSMalloc", referenced from:
      _main in minstdio3.o
  "_OSMalloc_Tagalloc", referenced from:
      _main in minstdio3.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [minstdio3] Error 1
```

-- EDITS --

*"Why are you not using the sbrk system call if you want low-level? This would match your use of write and shouldn't give any linking issues."* (from [CRD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/568283/crd))

> Using 'sbrk' (and it's cousin 'brk') was the original path I was headed down; however, the man page for 'sbrk' states, "The brk and sbrk functions are historical curiosities left over from earlier days before the advent of virtual memory management." This statement put me on a path toward trying to discover its replacement. 'malloc' is, of course, the correct and normal utility for memory allocation. However, K&R Chapter 8 is all about writing your own from base OS system calls. So, the base call I was able to find for OS X Darwin is 'OSMalloc' which I'm trying to use.

Comment: Why are you not using the [`sbrk` system call](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/brk.2.html) if you want low-level? This would match your use of `write` and shouldn't give any linking issues.

Comment: Using 'sbrk' (and it's cousin 'brk') was the original path I was headed down; however, the man page for 'sbrk' states, "The brk and sbrk functions are historical curiosities left over from earlier days before the advent of virtual memory management."  This statement put me on a path toward trying to discover its replacement.  'malloc' is, of course, the correct and normal utility for memory allocation. However, K&R Chapter 8 is all about writing your own from base OS system calls.  So, the base call I was able to find for OS X Darwin is 'OSMalloc' which I'm trying to use.

Comment: You might want to look at `vm_allocate`, Apple shows a sample usage [in this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MemoryAlloc.html)

Answer (score 0):

OSMalloc is only available for writing the kernel itself (kernel extensions, device drivers). User programs have to use sbrk.